# Display remote image with php proxy

Tags: php, image, proxy

I'm trying to display insecure remote images within my own `https php proxy` to avoid the `ssl` mixed mode messages.

Unfortunately the code below does not show the image and I don't understand why.

```
<?php
// get productid
$productid = $id;

// get product
$get_product = database::query("SELECT p.image as productimage FROM product p WHERE p.id = '$productid' ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
$product = database::fetch_array($get_product);

$productimage = $product['productimage'];

// get image info
$imginfo = getimagesize($productimage);

// set header according to image type
header("Content-type: $imginfo[mime]");

// display image
readfile($productimage);
die();
?>
```

I also tried `file_get_contents($productimage)` instead of readfile but both solutions don't display any images, just an empty square.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try to use Fiddler and see what's actually being returned...

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 12 Mar 2016 10:42:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2g PHP/5.3.26
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.26
Content-Length: 3
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/jpeg

Comment: Does "readfile" itself succeeds? Try to look at its return value...

Comment: How can I verify this?

Comment: According to the documentation readfile() returns the number of bytes that were read, or FALSE on failure. You can try to echo its return value, or maybe file_put_contents() it into some temporary file...

Comment: When I use file_get_contents($productimage) instead of readfile I get the same result.

Comment: Use strlen() or readfile()'s return value to determine the size of the data that was retrieved. Yes but you should verify what data is loaded from the file. Try to write it to another file and look at its content. If nothing gets loaded then verify that the file exists or check the permissions... It seems like getimagesize() that operates on the same file name does succeed so it seems unlikely that there is a problem with the file itself but I'd double-check it anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php ?

Maybe you have to send some headers before the image

Comment: I am sending the content-type header. Should be enough to display an image right?